# Load ForEach SQL into single CSV in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF where I am executing a stored procedure in a ForEach and using Copy Data to load the output into a CSV file

On each iteration of the ForEach the CSV is being cleared down and loading that iteration's data

I require it to preserve the already loaded data and insert the output from the iteration

The CSV should have a full dataset of all iterations

How can I achieve this? I tried using the "Merge Files" option in the Sink Copy Behavior but doesn't work for SQL to CSV

Comment: The expected CSV should contains all the rows in the foreach iteration only? Is it allowed to be cleared before the foreach activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @All About BI mentioned, currently the **append behavior** which you are looking for is **not supported**.

You can raise a **feature request** from the **ADF portal**.

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can check the below process to append data in CSV.

1. In my repro, I am generating the loop items using Set Variable activity and passing it to ForEach activity.
2. Inside `ForEach` activity, using `copy data` activity, executing the stored procedure in Source, and copying data of **Stored procedure** to a CSV file.

[image]

3. In the `Copy data` activity sink, generate the file name using the current item of **ForEach** loop, to get data into different files for each iteration. Also adding a constant to identify the file name which can be deleted at the end after merging the files.

**File_name**: `@concat('1_sp_sql_data_',string(item()),'.csv')`

[image]

4. Add another `copy data` activity after the `ForEach` activity, to combine all the files data from the ForEach iteration to a **single file**. Here I am using the wildcard path **(*)** to get all files from the folder.

[image]

5. In Sink, add the destination filename with copy behavior as **Merge files** to copy all source data to a single sink file.

[image]

6. After merging the files data is copied to a single file, but the files will not be deleted. So when you run the pipeline next time, there is a chance the old files were also been merged with new files again.

•   To avoid, this adding delete activity to **delete** the files generated in ForEach activity.

•   As I have added a constant to generate these files, it will be easy to delete the files based on the **filename** (deleting all files which **start with** **“1_”**).

[image]

[image]

Destination file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

Load each iteration data to a separate csv file.
Later union them all or merge

As right now we don't have the ability to append rows in csv.