# Append data to a file using REST API

Tags: api, rest, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Does any one have an example of appending data to a file stored in azure datalake from source using Data Factory and the rest API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update)

Can I use a copy activity with REST dataset on the sink side ?

Bellow is my pipeline, it consists of a copy activity inside a foreach loop. My requirement is : if the file already exists on the sink then append data to the same file. (the copy activity here overwrite the existing file with just the new data)

[image]

Sink :

[image]

Comment: Can you share what you already tried? And the articles that are related and why it does not fulfill your need. Thanks!

Comment: @koen I added more informations on the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the append data to a file in **Azure Data Lake** is not supported in the **Azure Data Factory**.

As a workaround,

1. Load multiple files using ForEach activity into data lake.
2. Merge the individual files to get a single file (final file) using copy data activity.
3. Delete the individual files after merging.

Please refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679563/load-foreach-sql-into-single-csv-in-azure-data-factory/69686281#69686281) thread for similar process.

Comment: thank you. I had used this solution without merging individual files. I think it'is the best one.
Their is another solution for whom who are using synapse analytics (or sql server with polybase) is to use CETAS (create external table as select) and replace the copy activity with a stored procedure to generate the output file.