# ADF append data to an onprem file server file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get data from an ADF variable and append it to a file available in an on-prem file server. I've also created a self hosted IR to connect to the on prem file server.

Thanks,
Sayed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Appending an existing file using the Azure data factory is not supported currently. You can raise a feature suggestion from the portal.

Alternatively, you can create a new file and then merge it with an existing file using copy data. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679563/load-foreach-sql-into-single-csv-in-azure-data-factory/69686281#69686281) for details on merging files.