# Append new rows to csv file in Azure blob using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline, which iterates through the query parameters of a REST API and I am using parameters to pass them in the relative URL.
When I dont specify any file name in the sink, the pipeline creates new csv for each record and when I specify the file name, it is overwritten everytime.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Appending rows to the existing file is currently not supported using the Azure data factory.

You can raise a feature request from ADF portal feedback.

[image]

**As a workaround,**

•   You can copy data to different files each time.

•   Add another copy activity to merge all the files into a single file.

•   Delete all other files generated initially except the final merged file using delete activity.

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69679563/load-foreach-sql-into-single-csv-in-azure-data-factory/69686281#69686281) for details on merging the files.