# How to get pipeline completion results on ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a pipeline that is calling another pipeline which has a `ForEach` activity and it's passing this value through a `DataFlow` activity.

My problem is that I need to see if a particular loop in the ForEach has succeeded or not, so that I can pass this information to another colleague and he can work on his notebooks on Synapse. I don't what is the best way to do this or the best practices also.

I know that I can get this information through Azure API, from Azure Metrics (monitor), but I still didn't found a way to get that and save as a file or ingest in a Kusto table for example.

I saw that now is possible to get the [Pipeline Return Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-return-value) from a pipeline, but I didn't understand how could I save this info on each loop to an output file (doesn't matter the file format now).

So I would have the pipeline name, date, status (success/failed) and the loop value.

This is my parent pipeline:

[image]

This is the child pipeline:

[image]

So every this the `ForEach` activity above succeed or not, I will add the requirement values into a file.

I don't have any SQL or Synapse database, neither an API to use the POST method, that's why my goal is to save this into a file and then I could ingest into a Kusto table, OR if possible ingest directly into a Kusto table. But in case it's also easy to get that information from a Kusto query from Azure Logs/Monitor/API (don't know which one) for each pipeline run, I would also **prefer this way** (so there wouldn't be any ingestion, only retrieval).

Comment: where you want to store that file in blob storage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the status for each loop if it got succeeded or not you need to store the status based on the execution of dataflow activity as if it succeeded then store succeed and if failed then store failed.

- To do it upload empty CSV file in blob storage.
- Then Add two copy activities to store the result for succeeded and failed with additional columns as below:

[image]

- In sink generate the file name using the current item of **ForEach** loop, to get data into different files for each iteration as `@concat('file_',item())`
- It will generate the separate file for each iteration

[image]

- Include an additional copy data activity following the ForEach operation to consolidate data from all iterations into a unified file using wildcards.

[image]

You can also check this similar [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69686281) to combine all files

Comment: Thank you very much for the high detailed answer Pratik! I was able to do all of that, my only problem is that my `.csv` file is being generated with headers but with no data, really odd. If I click on `Preview data` in the `Source` tab I can see the values on each columns, but not in the preview and neither in the final output file. I also was able to generate multiple sink files as your example, but none of them had data, only headers.